# Amazon mws ability to take notice of restricted products

Tags: java, amazon-mws

When I'm using my account api keys, which endpoint and which API do I need to hit to be able to tell if I can sell a given product or not?

Comment: Try to catch **Error** by **Code** istead of catching **response** hope that will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [products API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_Overview.html)?

You can check out the example response in the bottom of [this](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetMatchingProduct.html) page. It holds the properties of the product in question and I think you can deduce what you need from that.

Also, [this](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_IfNew.html) link if for the full API docs where I'm sure you can find more information.

**Edit:**

This is [Amazon's product guidelines](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_left_ac?ie=UTF8&nodeId=200463270). You can see which products can be sold in general and how they should be presented. The API can only be used on listed products i.e. products that are already ready to be sold

Comment: hi @Guy Grin thanks for your response, which call do I make exactly and what do I look for in response? Yes I have looked at products API, I invoked every single endpoint on that API, nothing I can see in the response that would indicate I can't sell that product

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow I think I might have misunderstood your original question. Are you looking for a property e.g. `isSaleable` for a given  product? Or do you want guidelines on which products can be generally sold on Amazon?

Comment: I m looking for something `isSaleable` yes, or maybe if I can determine the selability of the product based on few calls to api

Comment: I think you are confusing some things. Amazon has guidelines on which products can be sold in general and how they should be presented  - https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_left_ac?ie=UTF8&nodeId=200463270 - to me it would seem that once a product is already listed it can be sold but I might be missing your intentions. Try adding data - what are the details of the case. What are you building and what code have you used...

Comment: hi @Guy Grin I think you don't understand how amazon works, are you selling on the platform? "o me it would seem that once a product is already listed it can be sold" - This is what I want to know, which products can I list and which I cannot. If you are familiar with the platform you would know that there are some restricted products and categories.

Comment: Hi @GandalfStormCrow, the link I posted in my previous comment directs to Amazon's guidelines on which products can be listed and sold.  As far as I know the API can only be used on listed products i.e. products that are already ready to be sold.  Sorry if I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: too bad wish there was a way to find out if you can sell/list or not

Answer (score 2):

According to https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_left_ac?ie=UTF8&nodeId=200277040, prohibition depends on the country's law.So, no api outputs whether your all products are sellable or not.
"For some product categories, sellers may not create product listings without prior approval from Amazon. In addition, sellers may be required to obtain additional approval to list certain products in certain categories. To request access to a specific category, see" https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=14113001